# Populating a list-view with an arraylist

Tags: java, android, android-listview, arraylist

I keep getting this error http://prntscr.com/3qygj9  (Sorry, I couldnt copy and paste) from this segment of code

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> foodList = db.getAllFood();
    if(foodList.size() != 0){
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.foodListView);

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                foodList );

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please Use `ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>` instead of `ArrayAdapter<String>`

```
ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                foodList );
```

Answer (score 0):

The type you're using to build the `ArrayAdapter` does not look compatible at all.

To build an `ArrayAdapter<String>`, the last argument to the constructor should be of type `ArrayList<String>`. But in your code, the `foodList` variable you pass for that argument is of type `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`.